# Como arrumar Icone da Janela Secundaria no CustomTkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

Salve turma, estou com um problema com o ícone de janelas secundarias do CustomTkinter, criei uma def para chamar o ícone em novas janelas, porém ele esta sendo chamado na Janela secundaria e sendo sobreposto com o ícone padrão da lib, alguém sabe como resolver? Deixarei o código do ícone e de como estou chamando.

Código Ícone:

```
    #Funcao para setar o icone em cada janela aberta
    def iconeJanelas(self, root):
        #Procura o icone usando a lib os
        icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'assets', 'icon', 'Gunz-3.ico')
        if os.path.exists(icon_path):
            try:
                #Adiciona o icone na janela aberta
                root.iconbitmap(icon_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Erro ao carregar o icone: {e}')
        else:
            print(f'Error: O arquivo do icone nao foi encontrado no caminho: {icon_path}')
            print('Verificar com o Administrador do Sistema')
```

Código de como estou chamando o ícone:

```
    #Funcao que cria a janela de pesquisa do mercado livre        
    def pesquisaMercadoLivre(self):
        #Fecha a pagina inicial quando aberta a pagina de pesquisa
        self.root.withdraw()
        
        #Cria a pagina de pesquisa
        self.rootPesquisaML = customtkinter.CTkToplevel()
        self.rootPesquisaML.title('Pesquisa Mercado Livre')
        self.rootPesquisaML.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.rootPesquisaML.geometry('500x300')

        self.iconeJanelas(root=self.rootPesquisaML)
```